# What is the proper way to specify image dimensions for a background image in CSS?

Tags: css

I have things in a CSS file, such as this:

```
/* Total counts - mini icons */
span.count-facebook {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/facebook.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
span.count-plusone {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/plusone.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
span.count-twitter {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
span.count-linkedin {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/linkedin.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
span.count-stumble {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/stumble.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
span.count-digg {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/digg.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
span.count-delicious {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/delicious.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
span.count-pinit {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/pinit.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
span.count-reddit {
background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/reddit.png) no-repeat 1px center;
}
```

These icons, facebook.png and plusone.png, etc., are all 24px x 24px ... I **assume** that just adding height:24; width:24; for each .png instance would have nothing to do with the actual images, although I could be wrong.

Is it possible that I can include a height and width attribute for the actual background images?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to minify your code as below.

```
span.count-facebook, span.count-plusone{width:24px; height:24px;}

span.count-facebook {background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/facebook.png) no-repeat 1px center;}
span.count-plusone {background: #fff url(../images/mini-icons/plusone.png) no-repeat 1px center;}
```

What you can do is to just add the `width` and `height` to all the classes as those will be icons just by adding a `, (comma)`. This will minify your efforts to all the time adding `width` and `height`.

After declaring the classes for icons with `width` and `height`, you just need to redeclare them by just changing the `.png` names for them all.

An alternate solution would be to create an image sprite and declare the `image` with `width` and `height` dimensions for all and just changing `background-position` for all the same redeclared classes above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, Nathan.  I'm trying to understand your solution but basically what you're saying is just do the span.count-plusone, span.count-facebook{width:24px; height:24px;} for each one (in edited the question) ------ and then "redeclare the classes" by changing the .png names for each icon.  May I ask how I'd redeclare them in a CSS file?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. I have just created a fiddle to explain above. http://jsfiddle.net/4UBun/ Also, added the same in the answer. - @JasonWeber

Comment: Wow, perfect, Nathan! Thank you for taking the time to make that fiddle; now I understand what you were saying more clearly.  I made the changes to the code and things work perfect -- just now, they have a height and width attribute, so I'm good to go.  Thanks again for your time!